# Is there .Net4 BackgroundCopyManager.dll?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.0, microsoft-bits, bits-service

I have project I want to upgrade to .Net4 and it use BackgroundCopyManager.dll.

Anyone knows where can I download it's .Net4 version?

Thanks

you can see BackgroundCopyManager.dll manifest here:

```
// Metadata version: v2.0.50727
.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89 )                         // .z\V.4..
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}
.assembly BackgroundCopyManager
{
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.TypeLibVersionAttribute::.ctor(int32,
                                                                                                int32) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ) 
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.GuidAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 24 31 64 65 65 62 37 34 66 2D 37 39 31 35   // ..$1deeb74f-7915
                                                                                                  2D 34 35 36 30 2D 62 35 35 38 2D 39 31 38 63 38   // -4560-b558-918c8
                                                                                                  33 66 31 37 36 61 36 00 00 )                      // 3f176a6..
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 15 42 61 63 6B 67 72 6F 75 6E 64 43 6F 70   // ...BackgroundCop
                                                                                                                 79 4D 61 6E 61 67 65 72 00 00 )                   // yManager..
  .hash algorithm 0x00008004
  .ver 1:0:0:0
}
.module BackgroundCopyManager.dll
// MVID: {328E2CCE-D921-47C0-8344-CEF41B018FDF}
.imagebase 0x00400000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00000001    //  ILONLY
// Image base: 0x004F0000
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't very clear where you got the type library, it isn't provided as part of Windows.  You can create one though.  Do so from the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt so you'll get a .NET 4 compatible assembly.  Navigate to your project directory and execute these commands:

```
midl.exe "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\bits.idl" /tlb BackgroundCopyManager.tlb
tlbimp.exe BackgroundCopyManager.tlb
```

You'll now have an interop assembly, BackgroundCopyManager.dll, that you can add to your project with Project + Add Reference, Browse tab.  Check the dll into source control so you don't have to repeat these steps.  It isn't going to change for a long time, if ever.

Do make a note in the bug database on how to recreate the assembly, presumably this was done and forgotten the last time.  That happens.

Answer (score 0):

There's a new [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/Bits/bits-dot-net) page that talks about using BITS and C#, plus a brand-new c#/WPF sample on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/bits-manager). These demonstrate one way to use BITS and C#/.NET